# Conversion error from Collection element to Int64. Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

Im having issues on the following code when converting to Int64 or any big number. Any help is appreciated.

```
public static void GetDiskspace(string MachineName, string DriveLetter) 
{ 
  ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions(); 
  ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + MachineName + "\\root\\cimv2",  
  options); 
  scope.Connect(); 
  SelectQuery query1 = new SelectQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk"); 

  ManagementObjectSearcher searcher1 = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query1); 
  ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection1 = searcher1.Get(); 

  foreach (ManagementObject mo in queryCollection1) 
  { 
      // Display Logical Disks information 

      if (mo["Name"].Equals(DriveLetter.ToUpper()+":"))
          if (((Int64)mo["FreeSpace"]) < (1024 * 1024 * 100)) //100GB  <<----HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR
          {
              Console.WriteLine(MachineName + " ALERT. LOW SPACE ON DRIVE " + mo["Name"]);
              Console.WriteLine();
              Console.WriteLine("              Disk Name : {0}", mo["Name"]);
              Console.WriteLine("              Disk Size : {0}", mo["Size"]);
              Console.WriteLine("              FreeSpace : {0}", mo["FreeSpace"]);
              Console.WriteLine("          Disk DeviceID : {0}", mo["DeviceID"]);
              Console.WriteLine("        Disk VolumeName : {0}", mo["VolumeName"]);
              Console.WriteLine("        Disk SystemName : {0}", mo["SystemName"]);
              Console.WriteLine("Disk VolumeSerialNumber : {0}", mo["VolumeSerialNumber"]);
              Console.WriteLine();
          }
  } 
  string line; 
  line = Console.ReadLine();  
}
```

EDIT: changed "Size" to "FreeSpace".

Comment: What do you get for `mo["Size"].GetType()`?

Comment: a ulong object with value 96782405632

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `ulong` boxed into `object`. So you can only unbox it to `ulong` (i.e. `UInt64`).

```
 if (((UInt64)mo["Size"]) < (1024 * 1024 * 100))
```

[image]

Have a look at [Win32_LogicalDisk class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
class Win32_LogicalDisk : CIM_LogicalDisk
{
    ...
    uint64   Size;
    ...
};
```

An extract from `Win32_LogicalDisk` class properties description:

**Size**

```
Data type: uint64 
Access type: Read-only Size of the disk drive.
This property is inherited from CIM_LogicalDisk.
```

P.S.:

1) Actually if you do need to have `Int64`, you can do the following cast:

```
(Int64)(UInt64)mo["Size"]
```

2) You could read [this article by Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx), clarifying the essence of the exception in question.

Answer (score 2):

Use **[`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2x2b1h.aspx)** instead to check if the value is valid numeric or not.

```
long number;
bool result = Int64.TryParse(mo["Size"], out number);
```